# PHP7 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, php, php7

I would like to upgrade our production php version to new php7. Unfortunately we are currently running on ubuntu 12.04. I have already tried to install php7 on corresponding virtual machine using *ppa:ondrej/php* repository. It results with:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-fpm'
```

Is there a way to use new php7 features without upgrading our production environment? I am currently trying to compile it from source, but as I am not experienced with it I am not quite sure about its result.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7 is not available in the Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) official repositories, but you may be able to add it from a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/4990#4990) following a guide like [this one from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04) (though the DO one is for 14.04, so you'll have to adapt it a bit).

Notice that the [Ubuntu Developers maintained PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0) for PHP 7.0 is only available for Xenial and Yakkety.

Comment: Anybody got this to work? I added the PPA (had to first install `python-software-properties`), ran `apt-get update` (and `...upgrade` and `...dist-upgrade`), and had no errors - but no php7* package are available!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed apt-get update. When it runs, check whether it actually contacts launchpad for this PPA.

Comment: Can you expand your answer please?

Comment: Once you add a PPA, it's like with any other APT source: you need to run apt-get update before the package becomes installable with apt-get install